# Configure DNS servers on multi-homed EC2 instance running Windows 2016 server

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, internal-dns, multi-homed

I need help configuring DNS servers for a multi-homed EC2 instance running Windows 2016 server. This instance has 2 network interfaces attached to it, eth0 and eth1. I have setup routing policies to ensure that traffic destined to a cidr range egresses through eth1 and everything else goes out through eth0. Now I want this instance to join an AD domain, and make sure that traffic destined to the same Cidr range (mentioned earlier) uses AD domain controllers for DNS resolution, all other requests should use Amazon provided DNS server.

How can I accomplish this?

Do I need to run a local DNS server and use stub zones/conditional forwarders? Can’t I set desired DNS IP addresses in individual network adapter’s ipv4 properties?

Comment: If there is already an ip-address then you are too late for DNS. Except for reverse pointer look-up. Your use case may be different. If you want to give AD DNS priority, then lower the metric of the AD interface. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/network-subsystem/net-sub-interface-metric

Comment: No, I will launch a new instance. I've given lower metric to eth0 (non-AD interface), but I'd imagine that the preference is only to route requests to the network interfaces, once the network interface is determined, DNS server associated with the network interface will be used. Do you know how it works?

Comment: DNS on lowest metric should be queried first. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd197552(v=ws.10)